# Replace faulty drives in a Dell T420

Tags: dell

I have a poweredge T420 with two "Predictive failure" disks.
Configuration is RAID-5. I'm hoping to hot-swap the disks 1 by 1 by  after marking each drive as failed.
In order to see the rebuild progress i was going to use "Open Manage"
But i have problems with "Open Manage" which is not solvable at the moment (Contacted dell about this & still waiting for a fix)
Is it possible to use "Lifecycle Controller" for the above mentioned purpose?

Comment: The answer is yes. You should boot into the lifecycle controller to see that, but it means a downtime. That's how it's going.

Comment: @batistuta09 thanks for the reply. Can i take disks offline from lifecycle controller?

Comment: Yup, via Hardware Configuration Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which controller you are using in the T420? I have user the 'MegaRaid' tool for Perc 5i / 6i / H200 and H700 controllers from Dell and found that it works really well for my purpose (And I can monitor the rebuilds and failures etc). I know it is re branded now to AVANGO but if you hunt around you can still download and use it.

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: It uses the PREC H710 adapter

Comment: I think the MegaRaid tool may well help you out. A link below:

https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search/?pg=&pf=&pn=MegaRAID+SAS+8408E&po=&pa=&dk=

Select Software & Tools, Then the Windows version of the MegaRAID Storgae Manager.

P.S. Username and password are the same as your Windows Login Details.